# Counterfactual symbol on GitHub pages with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, mathjax

- I use [Jekyll Now](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now) for my blog
- It uses Kramdown to parse Markdown, and to pass Math to MathJax
- I want to use a counterfactual conditional like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQe5n.png)

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Which part of this is giving you trouble? Are you asking how to generate that symbol in MathJax? Or something else? Please try to isolate your problem to just one library or framework.

Comment: The way I would usually do this would be by importing a latex package that includes the symbol. But with MathJax, you can't import packages (or is the problem kramdown?). So generating the symbol in MathJax would be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the STIX fonts, or the LatinModern or any of the other web fonts, you could do something like

```
\mathbin{\square\!\mathord\to}
```

I don't know what class this character is supposed to have, but I made it a BIN (binary operator) as an example.  Change `\mathbin` to the appropriate value.

If you are using the default MathJax font, however, you might prefer

```
\mathbin{\lower.1em\square\!\mathord\to}
```

Whichever you prefer, you probably want to change your configuration to force the font you want, as the default configuration for HTML-CSS output allows either STIX or MathJax fonts.

Comment: ah `\mathord` was the missing piece!